# Assembly 8086: Append at the end of file

Tags: assembly

I know this is a simple problem, but I really don't know how to solve this. 
I'm using this code

```
mov bx, handle
mov dx, offset data
mov cx, 100
mov ah, 40h
int 21h
```

to write to a file. But I need to "update" it; sort of like appending at the end of it. Is it possible? If so, how would I do it? Is there a specific instruction for it? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
.model small
.data
    filename db "test1.txt", 0
    handle dw ?
    data db "write me! "
    buffer db 200 dup(' ') 
    errormess db "Error in opening file!$"
.stack 100h
.code

    main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov AH,3dh
    mov AL,2
    lea dx,filename
    int 21h

    mov handle,AX
    jc erroropen
    jmp noerror
    erroropen:
        lea dx, errormess
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        jmp exit
    noerror:

    mov bx, handle
    mov ah, 42h  ; "lseek"
    mov al, 2    ; position relative to end of file
    mov cx, 0    ; offset MSW
    mov dx, 0    ; offset LSW
    int 21h

    ;mov bx, handle
    mov dx, offset data
    mov cx, 100
    mov ah, 40h
    int 21h ; write to file...

    mov bx, handle
    mov ah, 3eh
    int 21h ; close file... 

    exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

    main endp
    end main
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use [function 42h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah42) (`lseek`) and position to the end of the file before writing:

```
; assuming "bx" holds the file handle

mov ah, 42h  ; "lseek"
mov al, 2    ; position relative to end of file
mov cx, 0    ; offset MSW
mov dx, 0    ; offset LSW
int 21h

; current position (= file length) now in dx:ax
; write here...
```

(wow, I never thought I'd fiddle with DOS interrupts again ;-).

**UPDATE:** Assembled with [nasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) (you'll have to adapt the syntax), tested with [dosemu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSEMU):

```
   org 100h

section .code

start:
   mov ah, 3dh
   mov al, 2
   mov dx, filename
   int 21h
   jc err_open

   mov [handle], ax

   mov bx, ax
   mov ah, 42h  ; "lseek"
   mov al, 2    ; position relative to end of file
   mov cx, 0    ; offset MSW
   mov dx, 0    ; offset LSW
   int 21h
   jc err_seek

   mov bx, [handle]
   mov dx, usermsg
   mov cx, 100
   mov ah, 40h
   int 21h ; write to file...
   jc err_write

   mov bx, [handle]
   mov ah, 3eh
   int 21h ; close file...
   jc err_close

exit:
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h

err_open:
   mov dx, msg_open
   jmp error

err_seek:   
   mov dx, msg_seek
   jmp error

err_write:
   mov dx, msg_write
   jmp error

err_close:
   mov dx, msg_close
   ; fallthrough

error:
   mov ah, 09h
   int 21h

   mov ax, 4c01h
   int 21h


section .data

filename:  db "test1.txt", 0
handle:    dw 0
usermsg:   db "write me", 0
buffer:    times 200 db 0
msg_open:  db "Error opening file!$"
msg_seek:  db "Error seeking file!$"
msg_write: db "Error writing file!$"
msg_close: db "Error closing file!$"
```

That's probably more DOS than I wanted to for tonight :-)

```
% echo "bla" > ~/.dosemu/drive_c/test1.txt 
% dosemu
```

[image]

Comment: Just edited my post with my version of the code, it "works for me" with nasm and dosemu;  I've tried to stick to the traditional intel syntax, but you'll probably need some small adjusments here and there (`lea`, `mov ax,@data; mov ds,ax`, etc..).  Cheers.